# How do I fix this syntax error on my Try and Except

Tags: python, discord.py, bots

I am making a discord bot and I am adding a music feature but when I run it it gives me a syntax error on my exception and I couldn't find a solution.

```
def search_yt(self,item):
  with YoutubeDL(self.YDL_OPTIONS) as ydl:
    try:
       info = ydl.extract_info("ytsearch:%s" % item, download=False)['entries'[0]
    except Exception:
          return False
  return {'source': info['formats'[0]['0']], 'title': info['title']}
```

[image]

Comment: The previous line has an unclosed `[` - and probably has more wrong with it than that, as the last part of it makes no sense as you've currently written it.

Comment: Thanks that solved the problem and the last part is not complete I just took the part of the code that had the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using mixed indentation and there's a missing `]` on the fourth line.
Here's a properly formatted code (though it has other issues, so will probably not work):

```py
def search_yt(self,item):
    with YoutubeDL(self.YDL_OPTIONS) as ydl:
        try:
            info = ydl.extract_info("ytsearch:%s" % item, download=False)['entries'[0]]
        except Exception as e:
            return False
        return {'source': info['formats'[0]['0']], 'title': info['title']}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all your code is not spaced well use TAB and not spaces(I would recement you to use the indent-rainbow module on visual studio.
Second you have forgotten an ] on line 4

```
def search_yt(self,item):
    with YoutubeDL(self.YDL_OPTIONS) as ydl:
        try:
            info = ydl.extract_info("ytsearch:%s" % item, download=False)['entries'[0]]
        except Exception:
            return False
    return {'source': info['formats'[0]['0']], 'title': info['title']}
```

Comment: " use TAB and not spaces"  - the opposite is recommended: use 4 spaces for indentation.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation for indent-rainbow :)